# List comprehension (python)and array comprehension (php)?

Tags: php, python, arrays, arraylist

```
>>> lst = ['dingo', 'wombat', 'wallaby']
>>> [w.title() for w in lst]
['Dingo', 'Wombat', 'Wallaby']
>>>
```

In python there is simple ways to todo with list comprehension.

What about in php with `array('dingo', 'wombat', 'wallaby');` ?

Are there array comprehension or any build in function ,or normally loop on it?

EDIT

```
function addCaps( Iterator $it )
{
    echo ucfirst( $it->current() ) . '<br />';
    return true;
}

/*** an array of aussies ***/
$array = array( 'dingo', 'wombat', 'wallaby' );

try
{
    $it = new ArrayIterator( $array );
    iterator_apply( $it, 'addCaps', array($it) );
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
    /*** echo the error message ***/
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Look the code not too simple like I expected?

Comment: Nitpicking: `list` is a pretty useless name and shadows a builtin.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [`array_map()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) with anonymous functions (closures are PHP 5.3+ only).

```
$arr = array_map(function($el) { return $el[0]; }, array('dingo', 'wombat', 'wallaby'));
print_r($arr);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => d
    [1] => w
    [2] => w
)
```

Edit: OP's sample code

```
$arr = array_map('ucwords', array('dingo', 'wombat', 'wallaby'));
print_r($arr);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Dingo
    [1] => Wombat
    [2] => Wallaby
)
```

Comment: Closures are anonymous functions. More info: http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php

Comment: It's *not* a [closure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/closures?sort=votes&pagesize=50), as it doesn't "capture" variables from the outside. Merely an anonymous function.

Comment: why it call like anonymous? :) ,sorry I really need understand by you than read long docs. thanks

Comment: @IEnAk: Declaring a `function foo($x) { return $x; }` creates a function that's bound to the name `foo`. The function literal, or anonymous function `function ($x) { return $x; }` doesn't have a name on its own. Sure, you can assign it to a variable so you have a name that refers to that function, but it doesn't need one.

Comment: Is this faster than the plain ol' `foreach`?

Comment: @Dor, haven't tested, but pretty sure it will be slower than `foreach`.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have array comprehensions for PHP. You do have functions like `array_walk()` similar to the `map()` function of python.

Answer (score 2):

[`array_map()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) and [`array_filter()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php)